# Enums instantiated as a callable show errors but the code works when using VS Code Pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

I have a class like this:

```
from enum import Enum


class BaseEnum(str, Enum):
    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [c.value for c in cls]

    @classmethod
    def names(cls):
        return [c.name for c in cls]
```

... which i use like this:

```
FruitEnum = BaseEnum("Fruits", ["Banana", "Apple", "Kiwi"])

fruits = FruitEnum.values()
```

The code works perfectly fine, but pylance throws me an error for the functions from the BaseEnum class. It somehow does not detect or accept them, `.values()` is red underlined and vscode shows the following error message on hover:

> ```
> Cannot access member "values" for type "Type[Enum]"
>   Member "values" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
> (function) values: Unknown
> ```

Is there a way to get rid of this error or add it to an exception list or so?